# When does Luffy return to Alabasta after getting defeated by Crocodile in their first fight?

Tags: one-piece

Please tell me the exact episode range. Like, 111-135 or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

**Episode 121**

After getting defeated by Crocodile in **Episode 110**, Luffy is seen carried by Pell in a really bad condition and he finally makes an appearance back in Alabasta when he saves Vivi from Crocodile in **Episode 121**.